# Cannot print string from stringFromDate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to pass the date to a `NSLabel` using the `stringFromDate` in swift, but the `timerString` isn't being passed anything and won't print to the console.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
func printGameTime(timer: NSDate)
{
    let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    var timerString = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(timer)
    print("Printing: \(timerString)")
}
```

Comment: Your issue isn't clear. In the code you posted, what happens? What should happen?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call printGameTime function.

Comment: The function gets passed the time declared as date `date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: NSTimeIntervalSince1970)`. Then, I'm trying to convert the date to a string to print it onto a label using another function at the bottom (that's not included above)

When called, "Print: " is printing to the console, but timerString isn't.

Comment: If your `printGameTime` function is a timer callback, the parameter is not going to be an `NSDate`, but rather an `NSTimer`. How is printGameTime being called?

Comment: I pasted your code in a playground and it does print "Printing: 1:00:00AM". That's assuming you pass in timer as mentioned in your comment (which by the way is always Jan 2, 2032, 1:00:00AM in UTC+1)

Comment: by the way, you can print("Raw timer value: \\(timer)") to check the value of your timer before formatting.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's replies. I figured out that there was a bug when calling the timer that was supposed to run the function. I apologise for not posting the timer code that was obviously more important. #newbie